# Blank VBA module - User-deifined type not defined

Tags: vba, outlook

I have a blank Outlook VBA Pad. No code in it whatsover. I type in

```
dim a as string
```

, or even just insert a space, and force a recompile and I get the following error:

> (User-defined type not defined.)

Anyone else seen this and have a remedy for it?

For clarity - my example above was just an example.  if I remove the dim statement and simple add a space (and then force a recompile) the error occurs. In other words there is absolutely no code whatsoever in any module or form and this error occurs

Comment: VBA Pad being VBA module (btw)

Comment: Stupid question, but you are putting your dim statement inside of a subroutine correct?

Comment: Do you reference any other VBA project that might contain the error?

Comment: [Getting Started with VBA in Outlook](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee814736(v=office.14).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

When declaring variables outside procedure use

**`Public or Private a as string`**

for `Dim statement` use within a procedure

```
sub example
   dim a as string
end sub
```

[See MSDN on Declaring Variables](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264241.aspx#Using%20the%20Public%20Statementhttp://)